# Is IBAction causing NSOpenPanel modal to auto close?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsopenpanel

Why does calling [openPanel runModal] in function load: cause the openpanel to autoclose? It works fine when calling function load.

```
- (void)load {
    if ([self.openPanel runModal] == NSModalResponseOK) { //works correctly
        NSArray *files = [self.openPanel URLs];
    }
}

- (IBAction)load:(id)sender {
    if ([self.openPanel runModal] == NSModalResponseOK) { //returns immediately
        NSArray *files = [self.openPanel URLs];
    }
}
```

UPDATE

I create my nsopenpanel in viewDidLoad

```
self.openPanel = [[NSOpenPanel alloc]init];
[self.openPanel setCanChooseFiles:YES];
[self.openPanel setAllowsMultipleSelection:FALSE];
```

Comment: Objective-C 101 - You don't create an NSOpenPanel object.  That's not the way how you use NSOpenPanel.

Comment: @ElTomato I'm not that dumb...